# How can I appear in "Web Results" section of Google Map's search?

Tags: seo, google-maps

A user searches for something on Google Maps and clicks on one item from the list. A panel appears on the left (or right) side of the screen that contains information about that searched entity and its website images reviews, etc.

[image]

At the bottom of that panel, there is this section called `Web Results`.

[image]

How can I appear there? I have many URLs on my website that are the link to one of Google's SERP, but they don't appear there.

Is there a special thing that I should do to appear there?

Answer (score 1):

The "web results" appear from the publicly available information of the own official website as well as from third parties from company directories or relevant profiles.

In our experience, the web results are the *own website pages*, *social media profiles* (facebook) as well as referrals from *company directories* (citations) that have given the consumer the most benefit and have the most signals with a local company.

This means that these *results are flexible* and adapt to the most trusted sources.

Google plays here e.g. the Facebook profile and/or yelp (golocal/wlw in Germany) data out, as well as the suitable web page which fits to the search inquiry.

**How to influence these results?**

1. Fill in all relevant company directories (local citations) with the correct NAP* data.
2. Create the most important social media profiles + don't forget the NAP!
3. Optimize your website for local search = LocalBusiness/Organization Schema Markup (hasMap, sameAs etc.) + Google Business linking (e.g. in footer) + relevant content with local keywords.

**NAP = Name, Address, Phone number*

Here is the official explanation from Google itself:
https://support.google.com/local-listings/answer/9851099?authuser=0&hl=en&visit_id=638301080773941426-4217701888&p=how_google_sources&rd=1&sjid=1938301653704286425-EU

Answer (score 0):

These are local search directories that are competitors to Google business. You can sign up for them and in theory show up for these searches.

So, sometimes pages from competitors to Google business are shown in google searches in Europe. This means yelp and Facebook business pages in the USA. This varies regionally in different areas different companies are popular. Because you are in Europe, I believe there were a series of court case that were lodged against google claiming they were violating anti trust laws and they had to, "show their competitors" on their own website. While the UK isn't part of the EU. It often gets lumped in so that areas in France (like dunkirk) don't accidentally violate the laws when someone's phone picks up a signal from the UK.

Here is a list of the top local search directories in the UK. Basically, sign up for all of these or a good chunk of them and then you can show up for local search competitor listings.
https://www.woorank.com/en/blog/free-business-directories-uk

Here are a few examples of all the court cases where google was forced to show competitors in their searches in Europe due to anti trust laws:
https://techcrunch.com/2022/06/21/google-maps-germany-fco-antitrust/
https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-google-eu/eu-accuses-google-of-hurting-consumers-competitors-in-web-search-case-idUKKBN0N523220150415
https://searchengineland.com/europe-turns-antitrust-attention-to-google-maps-on-android-235796

Answer (score -1):

For that you need to add your business details in Google business listing.
https://business.google.com/locations
Google shows company information, distance, reviews & ratings everything from their business listing data.
Optimized business listing can bring a lot of business.

Web results section is some resources about that business picked by Google. Read the following official documentation about that.

[How Google sources and uses information in local listings](https://support.google.com/local-listings/answer/9851099)

Comment: Adding business details through GMB affects how the top sections of the panel are displayed; I don't believe it affects the "Web results" panel that is being asked about here, at least not in any direct way.

Comment: yes absolutely. I have  edited that.